# Find and replace dynamically using linq

Tags: linq

I have to update my `collection` searching for the `field` sent as `parameter` and `replace` the `values` in it for the `old values`..

Like *`p.ItemName`* i have to do that for 426 properties which is tediuos job.. I need to generalize the italicised code..

```
 private void UpdateCollection(string fieldName, List<MarketRecord.FItemExtended> fitems , string oldVal , string newval)
        {

            PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(MarketRecord.FItemExtended).GetProperties();         



            *var collectionToUpdate = fitems.Where(p => p.ItemName == oldVal).ToList();
            collectionToUpdate.ForEach(x => x.ItemName = newval);*
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the PropertyInfo objects and call the getter and setter on each property using reflection. It won't necessarily be in Linq, as maybe loops will be more readable here.